# R ggplot: Change spacing between two different legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar chart (`geom_col`), combined with a single data point (`geom_point`) for each bar. The graph currently looks as follows: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpOf5.png). How do I change the horizontal spacing between the 2 different legends? I.e., I want to remove the excess horizontal spacing between 'Liabilities' and '◆ Net wealth'.

The following code produces a minimal example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(quintile = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
            class = c("real_assets", "fin_assets", "liabilities", "net_wealth"),
            value = c(349874, 29449, -12233, 367090))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(class != "net_wealth"),
           aes(x=quintile, y=value, fill=class), position = "stack") +
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(class == "net_wealth"),
             aes(x=quintile, y=value, shape=class)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

I tried adjusting `legend.box.margin`, `legend.spacing.x`, and `legend.margin`. However, this did not give the wanted result.

Comment: Can we have a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code for better understanding please.

Comment: How did you try those options? Something like `legend.margin = margin(), legend.spacing.x = unit(2, "pt")` looks pretty tight to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the right theme settings. The legend box surrounds both legends together, so `legend.box.margin` it won't be useful here, but we can set the `legend.margin = margin()` (the defaults are 0 when you call `margin()`) and `legend.spacing.x` to a small value, the legends look nice and close together:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(class != "net_wealth"),
           aes(x=quintile, y=value, fill=class), position = "stack") +
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(class == "net_wealth"),
             aes(x=quintile, y=value, shape=class)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.margin = margin(), 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(2, "pt")
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A second option would be to merge both legends by setting the `limits` for both scales to include all categories of `class` and by appropriately setting the `values=`, i.e. set the `shape` to `NA` for all categories except `"net_wealth"` and vice versa the `fill` to `"transparent"` for `"net_wealth"`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    data = df %>% filter(class != "net_wealth"),
    aes(x = quintile, y = value, fill = class), 
    position = "stack"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = df %>% filter(class == "net_wealth"),
    aes(x = quintile, y = value, shape = class)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(scales::hue_pal()(3), "transparent"),
    limits = unique(df$class)
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(rep(NA, 3), 16),
    limits = unique(df$class)
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```

[image]